# How to create GitHub Actions for unit testing in .NET projects?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, github, nunit, github-actions

I use NUnit framework to test my .NET project. I want to run my tests via GitHub Actions.

What should be included in the assembly of my project? Maybe there are some standard examples?

Comment: You'll likely find better answers on the DevOps SE because this isn't really a coding issue.

Comment: DevOps SE: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/10499/how-to-create-github-actions-for-unit-testing-in-net-projects

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not need to include anything into your assembly to run your tests using GitHub Actions. Just create workflow file in `.github/workflows` folder with the following content (assuming that you have .NET Core project):

```yaml
---
name: Tests

on: push

jobs:
  tests:
    name: Unit Testing
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0
      - run: dotnet test
```

> `dotnet` is pre-installed on `windows` machine but is not pre-installed on `macos` and `ubuntu`. So, you have to install `dotnet` by adding an extra step in case you want to run it on one of these machines. You can use [actions/setup-dotnet](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-net-core-sdk) action for this purpose.

Comment: This answer is for dotnet core.  Question was for .NET Framework

Comment: @AndrewGray Author didn't specify what .NET configuration he is interested in, that's why I put "assuming that you have .NET Core project" in my answer. Also, from the comments it seems that this answer works for the author. Damián Pereira, the idea is just to run the same "test" command in GitHub Ations that you run locally. What kind of issue do you have?

Comment: for .NET Framework, see here https://stackoverflow.com/q/67770726/2006246