# How do i run nunit unit tests from Github Actions

Tags: c#, github-actions

I have a Xamrain Forms app that I wish to run my unit tests on commit how Do I add it into github actions.

Is their a way to block the build if the tests fail

```
name: CI on Push and Pull Request

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  Practice:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Run a one-line script
      run: echo Hello, world!
    - name: Run a multi-line script
      run: |
        echo Add other actions to build,
        echo test, and deploy your project.
    - name: Show what's in the directory
      run: |
        ls
    - name: Show what all is in the parent directory
      run: |
        cd ..
        ls
        
  Android:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Android
      run: |
        nuget restore
        cd THEHOCKEYLAB.Android/
        msbuild THEHOCKEYLAB.Android.csproj /verbosity:normal /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug
        
  iOS:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: iOS
      run: |
        nuget restore
        msbuild THEHOCKEYLAB.iOS.csproj /verbosity:normal /t:Rebuild /p:Platform=iPhoneSimulator /p:Configuration=Debug
```

The Structure of the project is as such

[image]

I am using nunit thanks. Also I need to make a custom nuget for devexpress mobile controls as their provided free they dont have a nuget feed any suggestions here.

Comment: There's the [`jobs.<job_id>.if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif) syntax. Follow the link for an example.

Comment: Their two parts to my question

Comment: A comment is not an answer. Anyhow, did you google it? It seems [this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67770726) answers your question.

Comment: Its not a comment! its in the body of the question read read

Comment: I was talking about *my* comment. Your comment on my comment is that it's incomplete. So I say: it's just a comment.